# Python - Numpy shape

Tags: python, numpy

I came across this statement:

```
numpy.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])
```

I saw the [numpy.zeros](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) documentation, and not sure how to interpret the above statement.

Can you kindly aid me on that? Is shape basically the dimensions of the array?

Thanks.

Comment: yes it is as you could read in the doc...

Comment: NumPy docs have a good explanation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.shape.html

Answer (score 3):

`X.shape` returns you a tuple, so `shape[1]` is the second item in this tuple. Therefore `1 + shape[1]` is adding one to the second dimension of `X`, giving the size of a new 1-D array filled with zeros when you do `np.zeros(1 + X.shape[1])`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What would be the tuple contents for X.shape?

Comment: @Simplicity the content for a 2-D array would be the number of rows `n` and columns `m`, something like `(m, n)`. For higher-dimension arrays `X.shape` will contain the number of "rows" in each dimension